# Best Practice - Retrieve name from SQL

Tags: java, android, sql

This is how I'm currently retrieving the members' name from the SQL database based off their ID.

It works fine for now, but I don't think it is best practice to select in this way because if there were somehow duplicate IDs it could retrieve the wrong name.

**Is there a better way of doing this?**

```
public String getMemberName(int id) {
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM members where id = "+id, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(0);
}
```

Comment: If your database design explicitly forbids duplicate ids, which I suspect it should, then I see no issue here.

Comment: if `id` is a primary key then there should only ever be one record retrieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which implementation of SQL you are referring to, you might use:

```
"SELECT TOP(1) [name] FROM [<schema>].[members] 
WHERE [id] = " + id + " 
ORDER BY <what_to_order_by> ASC/DESC "...
```

You typically want to include the schema name of the table as it may not be in the default schema. You SELECT TOP(1) to only return 1 value, and you would typically ORDER BY what is required to establish uniqueness. Alternately, if there are multiple columns required to establish uniqueness you might do something like:

```
"SELECT TOP(1) [name] FROM [<schema>].[members] 
WHERE [id] = " + id + " AND [birth_date] = " + birth_date + "
ORDER BY <what_to_order_by> ASC/DESC "...
```

This is all assuming that the [id] column is not unique. If it is the primary key or unique you should still probably program defensively as I've noted above.

Comment: how does selecting top 1 prevent you from getting the wrong name if there are duplicated ids? even with `ORDER BY columnName ASC/DESC` doesn't necessarily mean it will retrieve what is expected.

Comment: Good point. I was multi-tasking and missed that. I edited my post to note that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your query as others have mentioned on the assumption that id is a primary key. If your database is designed this way, you will never have to worry about duplicate keys--it can't happen.

Regarding the query itself, maybe you could consider prepared statements. See https://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the rawQuery sometimes doesn't work with the WHERE clause. Try to use query().
[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)